# Python - NameError name "title" is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7

The dataset I am using is in multiple text files in the form:

```
#*TITLE1
#@AUTHOR1,AUTHOR2
#tYEAR
#cpublicationvenue
#index1
```

each block represents a paper. In my data set I have tens of thousands of these blocks. I want to insert this info into my database in which I have multiple tables. The code I have written below works perfectly SOMETIMES. Other times it will randomly give me an error when I try to populate the database such as:

```
NameError: name 'title' is not defined
```

I am at the stage now where I want to put all of this data into my database but I want to ensure this code has accounted for when a block for eg is missing the publication venue line and in that case just leave that column blank in that row.
This is the code I have written:

```
import MySQLdb


conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="xx", user="xx", db="xx")
db1 = conn.cursor()


with open("path/to/file", "rb") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("#*"):
            title = line[2:]

        elif line.startswith("#t"):
            year = line[2:]  # will ignore first two characters of line

        elif line.startswith("#c"):
            publication_venue = line[2:]

        elif line.startswith("#index"):
            ID = line[6:]

    elif line.startswith("#@"):
        author_list = line.split(",")
        author_list[0] = author_list[0][2:]  

    elif line.strip() == '':

        db1.execute('''INSERT INTO papers(
                ID, TITLE, YEAR, Publication_Venue)
                VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)''',
                (ID, title, year, publication_venue))


        for In_order, author in enumerate(author_list, start=1):
            In_order = In_order
            author = author

            db1.execute('''INSERT INTO authors(
                        ID, AUTHOR, In_order) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)''',
                        (ID, author, In_order))


        conn.commit()

        title = None
        year = None
        publication_venue = None
        ID = None
        author_list = None

    else:
        continue
```

Can someone tell me why I am getting this name error as I have clearly defined it in my code!!

Comment: Well, have you checked that `line.startswith("#*")` ever actually evaluates to true? Maybe by putting a print statement in that block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only defined `title` inside the first `if`:

```
if line.startswith("#*"):
    title = line[2:]
```

In case you don't get there (the line does not start with `#*`), it's undefined.
It becomes very clear that it is actually the issue since you specified that:

> The code I have written below works perfectly **sometimes**. Other times it will randomly give me an error when I try to populate the database.

Comment: When I say sometimes for example when I use one text file to populate the table it will work perfectly and all information is correctly inserted, but when I try another text file in the exact same format it will give me this name error. I can understand what you are saying about title only being defined in the 1st if statement. How would I go about fixing this error, should I be defining it in every if else? or should I be including the if else statements within this 1st if statement? Sorry I am new to python @Idos

Comment: @JohnPower you should add a `print` to actually keep track of its value. And to fix this it is preferable just to assign something to it (even `title = ' '`) **before** all the `if`s (before the `for`) to avoid code duplication.